File not downloading into Azure one Lake
I am currently engaged in the integration of data sourced from the Bing Ads API into our One Data Lake. While utilizing Fabric Notebooks for this task, I have successfully completed the authentication process. However, I have encountered an obstacle when attempting to download the data into our Azure Data Lake, as I am encountering the following error:
[An error occured in downloading campaign report:[Errno 2] Error occured:[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'abfss://{Workspace_name}@onelake.dfs.fabric.microsoft.com/{Lakehouse_Name}/Files/campaign_report.zip' MICROSOFT_ADVERTISING_MAIN : data extraction processing Failed !!!!: (<class 'FileNotFoundError'>, FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory'), <traceback object at 0x79d97dfc8640>)].
